# Handle slow response in web service calling in android

Tags: android

I have finished to write webservice in android.  But if there is no service or connection or network problem, webservice is searching for that.  It takes time.  How will handle webservice calling in slow response from webservice?

Can any one assist me to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the webservice from either a service ([docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)) or an AsyncTask ([docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)). If you're going to be interacting with the webservice for a while, then I would use the former. Otherwise, I would use an AsyncTask. The main thing to remember is make sure that you do NOT make this call on the main thread or your application will most likely block and Android will display an ANR dialog.

Also, note that, if you use a service, you need to start a new thread and launch the service from that thread to help prevent the application from blocking.

There's a tutorial [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android) that might be helpful.

Hope this helps!